# Python script can't find file when opening with VS code, but works OK with terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've got a python script which works with some files using normal

```py
with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
```

And there is input.txt in the same folder. Problem is, when I launch it with terminal, like

```
keddad@keddad-pc:~/bioinformatics-algorithms/1.3/PatternMatcher$ python3 ~/bioinformatics-algorithms/1.3/PatternMatcher/main.py
```

It works well, but when I try to run it with VS Code Debugger/Without debugger, it just can't find the files:

```
keddad@keddad-pc:~/bioinformatics-algorithms$ cd /home/keddad/bioinformatics-algorithms ; env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 /usr/bin/python3 /home/keddad/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.8.30787/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --nodebug --client --host localhost --port 46499 /home/keddad/bioinformatics-algorithms/1.3/PatternMatcher/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  "some traceback here"
  File "/home/keddad/bioinformatics-algorithms/1.3/PatternMatcher/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/keddad/bioinformatics-algorithms/1.3/PatternMatcher/main.py", line 10, in main
    with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.txt'
```

How can I make VS Code launch my scipts in a way that they find the files in the same directories?

Comment: In the launch config change the CWD to the folder `${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}`

Comment: @rioV8 Can you add this as an answer? I'd accept it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the [launch config](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) change the CWD to the folder

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            ....,
            "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So why does VS Code by default make the project root folder the current directory of the debugger? Does that mean it's better design to write all paths in sub-folders and sub-files relative to the project root directory?

Comment: @PeterElbert VSC has to choose a start directory to go to when opening the terminal, it can't be correct for everybody every time. That is why you can override the default with the `cwd` property, many people have 1 application in the workspace so it makes sense to choose the workspace root folder to start with. If you have many small python scripts use `cwd` property

Answer (score 1):

Your terminal in vscode is at this location: "~/bioinformatics-algorithms"

This is were the terminal executes the python code and search for the files. You have to change the terminal location to "~/bioinformatics-algorithms/1.3/PatternMatcher".

Comment: It doesn't really work this way: when launching, VS Code creates a new terminal located at the base folder of project ("~/bioinformatics-algorithms", in my case), so I can't do anything about it

Comment: Could you provide the relative path in your code from project base folder?