# python vs-code run file.py in file.py directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hi everyOne i'm trying to migrate to vscode from spyder. There is a way to configure the vsCode to run the curren opend file.py in the file.py folder automatically (not having to change manually the folder for every new file I open).

Second I have a `file1.py` containing some functions and `main.py` where I `import file1`. Is there a way to get autocompletion of functions in `file` inside the main?

**Edit**

`launch.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: if you do `import file` it will never load stuff from`file1.py`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57698163/9938317

Comment: @rioV8 thanks! I've searched but cannot find anything, that soveld the problem!

Comment: what is your current `launch.json` - edit your question

Comment: there's a way to interactive terminal %matplotlib qt at start?.    here the json               
 {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: `%matplotlib` sound like Jupyter Notebooks

Comment: @rioV8 '%something' it's a magic command works for jupyter and iPython (interactive Python), allows you to run bash commands or set some things, in my case `%matplotlib qt` sets default graphic interpreter to qt (so I can get the plot in a separate windows and work interactively with it)