# "No such file or directory" error in VSCode when the .txt file is in the same folder as the Python program

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-code, directory, path

Recently got a new laptop, with that needed to transfer over my programs and projects. I made and then cloned a private repository on GitHub onto my new laptop, however anytime I run a program that needs to access any .txt files I get the same error. The .txt files are in the same folder as the program and it runs on my old laptop completely fine. Also any program that does not need to search for any external files works just fine. Provided a picture that shows the folder and the error given. [folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiTHs.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GC4Q.png)

Tried reinstalling VSCode, did not fix it. I assume I made a mistake with the the git repository or something. Appears to be a path issue of some sorts but was unable to find a solution online.

Edit: Relatively new to programming, also wanting to avoid hardcoding the absolute path as I am in school and my program needs to run on the markers computer.

Comment: Try providing the full path

Comment: Smells like a CWD inconsistency. Do you have different user settings.json for the different machines? Do you have a launch.json file? How exactly are you running your program? People advising you to hardcode absolute paths... I don't agree. Hardcoding absolute paths is bad for transferrability of programs... which is exactly the kind of problem you're dealing with right now.

Comment: @user Is the settings.json a VSCode thing or a macOS thing? I apologize if this is a dumb question, I am relatively new to programming. I also am wanting to avoid hardcoding absolute paths, as I have to submit assignments for classes and obviously the absolute path is different for me than the person who will mark my projects.

Comment: sorry maybe I should have been more clear. Here ya go: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings (settings.json is a VS Code thing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python script can't find file when opening with VS code, but works OK with terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676850/python-script-cant-find-file-when-opening-with-vs-code-but-works-ok-with-termi)

Answer (score 0):

You can note that the current folder in terminal is the worksapce instead of the folder where the file you ran was.

You can use the following codes to open:

```
with open('Lab 3\klingon-english.txt') as file:
```

You can also add **the path of klingon-english.txt** to environment variable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Right click on your text file which you want to open and copy path as shown. Now paste this path in your `open`function on python file where you have.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to avoid hard coding the full path, you can use `os.getcwd()` like this:

```py
import os
    
text_file = f"{os.getcwd()}\\subfolder\\file.txt"
```

The function `os.getcwd()` gets you a string of the current working directory.