# How can I change the default directory in VSC for Python files to execute the right folder?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I tried working on files in python and learned that vsc doesn't execute the right folder. It executes parental folder instead of sub folder.

highscore.txt has to be in parental folder workspace1 in order for it to work, i want it to be in sub folder snake-game, but then it's not working

[image: XX]

This is the error I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'highscore.txt'
```

Edit: I'm using code runner in order to run code

I changed this setting but it didn't do anything

[image: it is enabled]

I've got absolutely no idea how to work on directories, could someone tell me what to change and where to fix it.

Comment: Can you be more specific: what file is not found? How are you referencing it? What are you trying to execute and how are you executing it?

Comment: this is how i open code:
'''
with open("highscore.txt") as data:
            final = data.read()
            self.high_score = int(final)
'''

Comment: since highscore.txt is in a directory above, you should be able to just use a relative path: `with open("../highscore.txt" as data:`

Comment: @topsail the thing is that the code works, when highscore.txt is outside of snake-game folder. I want it to work with highscore.txt being inside of snake-game folder.
i'm using code runner to run code btw
here is the code runner option to run python code: "python": "python -u",

Comment: In your screenshot, highscore.txt is not in the snake-game folder. So maybe you just need to put it there??? Otherwise, please confirm where where the file really is, and where is the code that you are using to open the file, and what that code is!

Comment: **DON'T USE** Code Runner, use launch configs, and set the `cwd` to the dir of the current file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python script can't find file when opening with VS code, but works OK with terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676850/python-script-cant-find-file-when-opening-with-vs-code-but-works-ok-with-termi)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think running a code through a code runner may be problematic, but you should verify to make sure you wrote the right path and that your file is in the game folder.

Answer (score 0):

When you check `Execute in File Dir`, you have to use **Run Python File** button which provided by Python extension.

[image]

You can also add `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` to your `launch.json` and use debug mode.

If you insist on using the coder-runner extension, please search and check **File Directory As Cwd** in the settings.

[image]