# VS Code - Python code not opening file properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, visual-studio-code, libraries

I wrote this code to open a file in python using VS CODE -

```py
with open("Answer Words.txt") as Answer_Words_File:
    Answer_Words = Answer_Words_File.read()
```

But it says " FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Answer Words.txt' "
This code worked when I earlier used PyCharm since the text file and my python project are in the same folder.

I also tried using the file path or writing -
`Answer_Words = open("Answer Words.txt", "r")`

Nothing worked

Do I need to use some library?

Comment: Are you using the 'Run Python File' button? Check the VSCode terminal to see where the code is being executed from. Sometimes VSCode executes programs from outside the project directory, and the file you specified does not exist in that directory. A simple fix would be to navigate to the correct directory in terminal and run the file again. I'm not well-versed enough in VSCode to give a more permanent fix, sorry, you would have to change directory every time you opened up VSCode.

Comment: @toyotaSupra whitespace should not be an issue as the filename is quoted as a string

Comment: use a launch config and specify the `cwd`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57698163/9938317

Answer (score 0):

I hope your terminal is not in right path if the file is not opening.
To ensure that your file is available in the path you execute this code.
You can use the code mentioned below

```
import os
current_directory = os.getcwd()
files_in_directory = os.listdir(current_directory)

# Print the list of files
print("Files in the current directory:")
for file in files_in_directory:
    print(file)
```

Comment: Does that differ from just `os.listdir()`?

Answer (score 0):

My VS code default folder is in C:\User\user. If you save the 'Answer Words.txt' in the default folder, it should run properly. Or you can set the terminal to your operating folder, it works well too.

Comment: Can I change the default folder for my project specifically

Comment: It doesn't work when I specify the file path either

Comment: you can go settings --> Features --> Terminal ---> Integrated.cwd to specify your path.  You may check it here too https://youtu.be/M2_v8eTQul4?si=Tfr7VbK5Tzt8wv8T