# vs code how to make working folder as subfolder the running file sits

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I open a folder in vs code, under this folder, there is a subfolder, when I tried to run the python file under this subfolder. when i use os.getcwd() and it shows the working folder is still the folder vs code opens at, instead of the subfolder the running file sits.

How to change working folder to be the subfolder?

I used the method from below link by adding cwd into jason file and it still not working. when I use os.getcwd() and it still output the base folder instead of the subfolder the running file sits.

[Python script can't find file when opening with VS code, but works OK with terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676850/python-script-cant-find-file-when-opening-with-vs-code-but-works-ok-with-termi)

Thanks