# Cannot write to file using Python on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I try to write to a file in python, it will not create a new file in the directory.

For example, if I run a simple command:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("Hello, World!")
```

it will compile and run but it will not create the output.txt file unless I run it through the terminal with python file_name.py

Comment: What do you mean by "compile"? Python is interpreted. Are you sure you're looking in the right directory for `output.txt`? It won't necessarily be in the same directory as the code you're running.

Comment: @Chris Python is also compiled (to bytecode).

Comment: @Chris To be precise, Python code is compiled into bytecode and interpreted at runtime.

Comment: That's an implementation detail of CPython, and there's no distinct compile step. It's a weird thing to say unless there's a clear reason.

Comment: But Chris mentioned the main point: The file will be opened in the current working directory and that might or might not be the same directory where the Python script is in. In this case it seems to be different.

Comment: FWIW, this is probably related: [open() gives FileNotFoundError / IOError: '\[Errno 2\] No such file or directory'](/q/12201928/4518341). It's about *reading* a file, not writing, but if the root cause is the same (wrong working directory), a lot of the info is still useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is current working directory?](/q/45591428/4518341)

Comment: To be clear, the file *is* being created, otherwise you'd get an error. So that means it's just not where you think it is. Or there could be some sort of deeper issue like your hard drive is dying, which Python wouldn't be aware of, but you probably would've noticed something like that.

Comment: Add `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())` to the code.  That will tell you where the file was written.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57676850/9938317

Comment: How do you execute scripts? Do you know where your run command and working directory are?